# Split an IP address into Octets, then do some math on each of the Octets

Tags: javascript

I actually have this working, but its very ugly, and its keeping me awake at night trying to come up with an eloquent piece of code to accomplish it.

I need to take a series of strings representing IP Ranges and determine how many actual IP address that string would represent.  My approach has been to split that into 4 octets, then attempt to split each octet and do the math from there.

e.g.: 1.2.3.4-6 represents 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, and 1.2.3.6, thus I want to get the answer of 3 from this range.

To further complicate it, the string I'm starting with can be a list of such ranges from a text box, separated by newlines, so I need to look at each line individually, get the count of represented IP address, and finally, how many of the submitted ranges have this condition.

```
1.1.1.4-6     /* Represents 3 actual IP Addresses, need to know "3" */
2.2.3-10.255  /* Represents 8 actual IP Addresses, need to   know "8" */
3.3.3.3       /* No ranges specified, skip this
4.4.4.4       /* No ranges specified, skip this
```

Net result is that I want to know is that 2 lines contained a "range", which represent 8 IP addresses (3+8)

Any eloquent solutions would be appreciated by my sleep schedule. :
)

Comment: Do you want to know the line number of the lines that contain the ranges and the range total for each line or just the single overall total of all lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There you go:](http://jsfiddle.net/JQWD9/)

```
var ips = ["1.2.3.4", "2.3.4-6.7", "1.2.3.4-12"];
for(var i=0; i<ips.length; i++) {
    var num = 1;
    var ip = ips[i];
    var parts = ip.split('.');
    for(var j=0; j<parts.length; j++) {
        var part = parts[j];
        if(/-/.test(part)) {
            var range = part.split('-');
            num *= parseInt(range[1]) - parseInt(range[0]) + 1;
        }
    }
    alert(ip + " has " + num + " ips.");
}​
```

This code also handles ranges like `1.2.3-4.0-255` correctly (i.e. 256*2=512 ips in that range). The list items that have no ranges yield a total of 1 ips, and you can ignore them based on the resulting `num` if you don't need them.

You'll probably need to slightly modify my example, but I'm confident you won't have any trouble in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is how I would do it

```
var addr = '1.1.3-10.4-6';

function getNumAddresses(input) {
    var chunks = input.split('.');
    var result = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (chunks[i].indexOf('-') != -1) {
            var range = chunks[i].split('-');
            result *= parseInt(range[1]) -  parseInt(range[0]) + 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

alert(getNumAddresses(addr));
```

Comment: +1 for great answer, but doesn't return how many times it occurs in the list of IP ranges to check